# how to activate Page Control?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

The page control is not functioning, the dot is not changing when I scroll through View Controllers.

Heres the code in the .m:

```
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize pageControl;
@synthesize pageControlUsed = _pageControlUsed;
@synthesize page = _page;
@synthesize rotating = _rotating;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for (NSUInteger i =0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _page = 0;
    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:[self.childViewControllers count]];

    UIViewController *viewController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage];
    if (viewController.view.superview != nil) {
        [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.childViewControllers count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
}


- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= [self.childViewControllers count])
        return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if (controller == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}


// At the begin of scroll dragging, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
_pageControlUsed = NO;
}

// At the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _pageControlUsed = NO;
}
```

Heres the .h:

```
 // Scroll View 
 @interface LevelOneAViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender;
```

Im using storyboard and i've connected the

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl
```

-to the page control that is on my scroll view.

The 2 views controller .h:

```
@interface ViewControllerTwo : LevelOneAViewController {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *View1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *View2;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
```

and the .m:

```
@implementation ViewControllerTwo

@synthesize View1;
@synthesize View2;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"]];
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"]];

}
```

How do I solve this to make the dots move when the page gets scrolled to the current page?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate which page you are on and then setting the pageControl to that page. Try this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int newPage = lroundf(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width);
    _pageControl.currentPage = newPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to implement delegate calls fired from the underlying scrollview

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

and set the currentPage like below,

```
pageControl.currentPage = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width);
```

Alternatively you can cycle through the subviews of pageControl and try to set the image, first subclass UIPageControl and in the implementation file add this

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    self.activeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagination_dot_active.png"] retain];
    self.inactiveImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"pagination_dot_up.png"] retain];

    return self;
}

-(void) updateDots
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIView* dotView = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView* dot = nil;

        for (UIView* subview in dotView.subviews)
        {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            {
                dot = (UIImageView*)subview;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (dot == nil)
        {
            dot = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, dotView.frame.size.width, dotView.frame.size.height)];
            [dotView addSubview:dot];
        }

        if (i == self.currentPage)
        {
            if(self.activeImage)
                dot.image = activeImage;
        }
        else
        {
            if (self.inactiveImage)
                dot.image = inactiveImage;
        }
    }
}

-(void) setCurrentPage:(NSInteger)page
{
    [super setCurrentPage:page];
    [self updateDots];
}
```

Declare the variables either in the header file or as a class extension

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *activeImage;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *inactiveImage;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Your link is only taking me to my Mega account page. I will edit my answer with a workaround though i would not recommend it.

Comment: Here try again: https://mega.co.nz/#F!0EkBQbTK!bKjEwFf7BQsUx0YGtoHehw

this one should work

Comment: The issue was twofold, autolayout caused the scrollview to occupy the whole screen, i unchecked Use Autolayout for storyboard.
Secondly, select the pageControl element in storyboard and change its autosizing property to make it stay relative to the bottom of the view. https://mega.co.nz/#F!wdhAyIBA!Y38s3jCLXLxU0-MEi9bXjg

Comment: I cant seem to figure out the autosizing property that makes it stay relative to the bottom of the view, could you elaborate on that please! did you get it to work?